# Disable/Enable columns based upon content of another column

Tags: permissions, column, custom-list

In a custom list I have 2 columns.  Column A is a drop down selection, lets say the selections are True/False for simplicity.

What I want to do is have a second column that is either Enable/Visible or Disabled/Hidden on the form based upon the value of Column A.

If A=False then Enable B

Is this possible on SP2010?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You have to customize your edit form with infopath.

Comment: Do you have a good 'info path for dummies' link?  I started messing with it but it was not very apparent how to get it done